# Select an associate all rows between a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a table with the following sample data:

```
20170426-31974-B
20170426-31980
20170426-32014
20170426-32609
20170426-32069-B
20170426-32649
20170426-32659
20170426-32669-B
20170426-32849
```

The values with -B are reference values. All the other files (without -B) should have a reference file associated with. So, all the gap between references (-B) should be associated with the previous "-B".

- Is there anyway, via query, of associating the lines to a reference "-B"?

What do I mean:

```
20170426-31980 -> reference to 20170426-31974-B
20170426-32014 -> reference to 20170426-31974-B
20170426-32609 -> reference to 20170426-31974-B
20170426-32649 -> reference to 20170426-32069-B
20170426-32659 -> reference to 20170426-32069-B
20170426-32849 -> refence to 20170426-32669-B
```

In other words, I need to get all the files between -B. All these files should be associated with the previous -B.

A select should return something like this

```
20170426-31980 || 20170426-31974-B
20170426-32014 || 20170426-31974-B
20170426-32609 || 20170426-31974-B
20170426-32649 || 20170426-32069-B
20170426-32659 || 20170426-32069-B
20170426-32849 || 20170426-32669-B
```

I tried [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736171/sql-select-all-rows-between-two-string-rows):

```
SELECT  FILE_NAME
FROM TBL_FILE_NAMES
CROSS APPLY(SELECT FILE_NAME) FROM TBL_FILE_NAMES WHERE file_name LIKE '%-B') CA_min(file_name)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT FILE_NAME) FROM TBL_FILE_NAMES WHERE file_name LIKE '%-B') CA_max(file_name)
WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt
```

But I believe that my logic is wrong. Should I try to use a cursor instead of query?

---

After some commentaries, the order matter. These names are created respecting a time. The first part of the file is the yearmonthday-seconds. My problem is that each file should have a reference (-B). How do know which files are associated with -B? It is the dates between the reference files.

```
20170426-31974-B.csv
20170426-31980.csv
20170426-31987.csv
20170426-31994.csv
20170426-32004.csv
20170426-32014.csv
20170426-32069-B.csv
20170426-32073.csv
20170426-32079.csv
20170426-32639.csv
20170426-32659.csv
20170426-32669-B.csv
20170426-32674.csv
```

In this case, I have my first reference 20170426-31974-B.csv. All the coming files (in order by time) until we reach a second reference should point to the first reference.

1. Reference 1 = 20170426-31974-B.csv

Values associated with

```
20170426-31980.csv
20170426-31987.csv
20170426-31994.csv
20170426-32004.csv
20170426-32014.csv
```

2. Reference 2 = 20170426-32069-B.csv

Values associate with

```
20170426-32073.csv
20170426-32079.csv
20170426-32639.csv
20170426-32659.csv
```

3. Reference 3: 20170426-32669-B.csv

values associated with

```
20170426-32674.csv
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Im missing something - how does `20170426-31980` relate to `20170426-31974-B`?

Comment: ugly it appears based on order.  Working backwards... 32849 associates to 32669-b because it's after the B.  32649 and 32659 associate to 32069-B again because they are AFTER the B and before the next -B so order matters.  so then the question becomes how do we denote order?

Comment: @Jamiec, I need the gap of names between "-Bs" associated with the previous "-B". There is not a relation between them. When I find a -B, all the coming values should be associated with this -B.

Comment: @xQbert, the order does not really matter because I do have another field (with dates) being used with an "order by".

Comment: @KannanKandasamy, I expect that each row will point o a -B. -B is a reference value. All the next files are associated with a reference.

Comment: Order matters alot w/o order we don't know which file names are between each of the `-B`s...

Comment: @xQbert, you are right, order matters and can be used. I updated my question, I hope that it is more clear now.

Comment: Still  I don't understand why `20170426-32609 -> reference to 20170426-31974-B`  why not `20170426-32609 -> reference to 20170426-32609-B` ?

Comment: What should happen if there is only a -B record w/o any other records? would you want to see it or not?

Comment: @Serg, it is a sequence, in time, of measurements. A sensor measures something and generates a file. In order, I will always start with a reference "-B", then I will have several other files and then another "-B". The files between "-Bs" should be referenced to "-B". These files should reference the previous -B. For example, I have 1st reference (-B).... Several files... 2nd reference (-B). All the "several files" will be associated with the 1st reference.

Comment: @xQbert, if there is a loose "-B", I really don't mind about it. What it is important for me it is to associate the files (without -B) to a reference (-B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
declare @t table(col varchar(100));
insert @t(col)
values
('20170426-31974-B')
,('20170426-31980')
,('20170426-32014')
,('20170426-32609')
,('20170426-32069-B')
,('20170426-32649')
,('20170426-32659')
,('20170426-32669-B')
,('20170426-32849');

with parent as (
    select col, strt = left(col,14), nxt = coalesce(left(lead(col) over(order by col), 14), '99999999-99999')
    from @t
    where right(col,2) ='-B' 
)
select parent.col, t1.col
from parent
-- left -- probably
join @t t1 on len(t1.col) = 14 and t1.col between parent.strt and parent.nxt
order by parent.col, t1.col
```

Comment: May need a left join if parents have no children and those need to display. +1 otherwise.  Be nice to avoid the hard-coded file name though (doubt that dates is ever hit while in use so still the +1).

Comment: Not sure on left join. Let me leave it at OP's discretion

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, I think this is what you're looking for...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    SomeValue VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    );
INSERT #TestData (SomeValue) VALUES 
    ('20170426-31974-B.csv'),
    ('20170426-31980.csv'),
    ('20170426-32014.csv'),
    ('20170426-32609.csv'),
    ('20170426-32069-B.csv'),
    ('20170426-32649.csv'),
    ('20170426-32659.csv'),
    ('20170426-32669-B.csv'),
    ('20170426-32849.csv');

-- SELECT * FROM #TestData td;

--==================================

WITH 
    cte_BaseStarts AS (
        SELECT 
            td.SomeValue,
            BaseValue = IIF(RIGHT(td.SomeValue, 5) = 'B.csv', td.SomeValue, NULL)
        FROM 
            #TestData td
        ),
    cte_FillAssocBase AS (
        SELECT 
            bs.SomeValue,
            AssocBaseValue = MAX(bs.BaseValue) OVER (ORDER BY bs.SomeValue ASC)
        FROM 
            cte_BaseStarts bs
        )
SELECT 
    fab.SomeValue,
    fab.AssocBaseValue
FROM 
    cte_FillAssocBase fab
WHERE 
    fab.SomeValue NOT LIKE '%B.csv';
```

Comment: Need to exclude the b to b association.  9 records in your result when I think there should only be 6

Comment: Good call... I've updated my answer. Also looks like the OP has updated the  sample data to include ".csv" appended to each of the values. Code has been updated to accommodate that as well.

Comment: Jason, it works! Both answers provided works really well. I will study both and use one of them. I mark as corrected the first one because it was posted before but your's also works! thank you

Comment: Glad to help. :)